# Does HERE have Parcel boundary data?

Tags: maps, here-api

Does HERE have data on property parcel boundaries?

I am looking for the coordinates of individual properties to overlay their maps.

Comment: Does anyone have experience with using Here parcel boundaries?

Comment: This is more of a customer support question to be directed specifically at a software company than the sort of specific programming question that's appropriate for SO. Take a look again at [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we do not have this kind of data available. Maybe this might be interesting for you:
Within the Reverse Geocode you can Request the shape of a postal district for a given latitude and longitude

This example retrieves the shape and details of the first address around a specified location in Chicago (41.8839,-87.6389) using a 150 meter radius to retrieve the address. The expected address is: 425 W Randolph St, Chicago, IL 60606, United States.   The addition of the additionaldata=IncludeShapeLevel,postalCode parameter ensures that the shape of the postal district is also included in the response. Reverse geocoding requests can be made using the reversegeocode endpoint and adding the prox parameter to the request URL. The number of results returned can be restricted using the maxresults parameter.

https://reverse.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/reversegeocode.json?prox=41.8839%2C-87.6389%2C150&mode=retrieveAddresses&maxresults=1&additionaldata=IncludeShapeLevel%2CpostalCode&gen=9&apiKey=xxx

```
{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      "Timestamp": "2020-07-27T09:56:24.943+0000",
      "NextPageInformation": "2"
    },
    "View": [
      {
        "_type": "SearchResultsViewType",
        "ViewId": 0,
        "Result": [
          {
            "Relevance": 1,
            "Distance": 16.3,
            "MatchLevel": "houseNumber",
            "MatchQuality": {
              "Country": 1,
              "State": 1,
              "County": 1,
              "City": 1,
              "District": 1,
              "Street": [
                1
              ],
              "HouseNumber": 1,
              "PostalCode": 1
            },
            "MatchType": "pointAddress",
            "Location": {
              "LocationId": "NT_puy2gbuVuGd-an6zGdSyNA_xADM",
              "LocationType": "address",
              "DisplayPosition": {
                "Latitude": 41.88403,
                "Longitude": -87.63881
              },
              "NavigationPosition": [
                {
                  "Latitude": 41.88401,
                  "Longitude": -87.63845
                }
              ],
              "MapView": {
                "TopLeft": {
                  "Latitude": 41.8851542,
                  "Longitude": -87.6403199
                },
                "BottomRight": {
                  "Latitude": 41.8829058,
                  "Longitude": -87.6373001
                }
              },
              "Address": {
                "Label": "100 N Riverside Plz, Chicago, IL 60606, United States",
                "Country": "USA",
                "State": "IL",
                "County": "Cook",
                "City": "Chicago",
                "District": "West Loop",
                "Street": "N Riverside Plz",
                "HouseNumber": "100",
                "PostalCode": "60606",
                "AdditionalData": [
                  {
                    "value": "United States",
                    "key": "CountryName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Illinois",
                    "key": "StateName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "Cook",
                    "key": "CountyName"
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "N",
                    "key": "PostalCodeType"
                  }
                ]
              },
              "MapReference": {
                "ReferenceId": "1190062166",
                "MapId": "NAAM20117",
                "MapVersion": "Q1/2020",
                "MapReleaseDate": "2020-06-29",
                "Spot": 0.59,
                "SideOfStreet": "left",
                "CountryId": "21000001",
                "StateId": "21002247",
                "CountyId": "21002623",
                "CityId": "21002647",
                "BuildingId": "9000000000002726912",
                "AddressId": "79186499",
                "RoadLinkId": "499349060"
              },
              "Shape": {
                "_type": "WKTShapeType",
                "Value": "MULTIPOLYGON (((-87.6339 41.88446, -87.6338 41.8813, -87.63239 41.88132, -87.63238 41.88067, -87.63378 41.88068, -87.63376 41.8794, -87.63377 41.87812, -87.6352 41.87811, -87.6352 41.87682, -87.63665 41.87678, -87.63663 41.87666, -87.63664 41.87658, -87.6367 41.87664, -87.63674 41.87678, -87.63706 41.87677, -87.6374 41.87807, -87.63756 41.87861, -87.63774 41.87936, -87.63794 41.88062, -87.63791 41.8819, -87.63779 41.88322, -87.63764 41.88449, -87.63727 41.88574, -87.63739 41.88602, -87.63603 41.88695, -87.63559 41.88717, -87.63248 41.8871, -87.63248 41.88703, -87.63374 41.88703, -87.63386 41.887, -87.63395 41.88702, -87.6339 41.88446)), ((-87.64102 41.87676, -87.64104 41.87804, -87.63955 41.87805, -87.63959 41.87933, -87.63966 41.88058, -87.63969 41.88187, -87.63976 41.88318, -87.6398 41.88446, -87.64022 41.88445, -87.64022 41.8846, -87.64025 41.88479, -87.64035 41.8851, -87.64047 41.88571, -87.63981 41.88572, -87.64062 41.88625, -87.64063 41.88639, -87.64064 41.88678, -87.63989 41.88679, -87.63993 41.88758, -87.6401 41.88769, -87.64035 41.88782, -87.64054 41.8879, -87.6407 41.88793, -87.64076 41.88828, -87.64085 41.88859, -87.63996 41.88847, -87.63999 41.88906, -87.63971 41.88905, -87.63961 41.88882, -87.63954 41.8887, -87.63918 41.88675, -87.63873 41.8864, -87.63841 41.88588, -87.6383 41.88573, -87.63812 41.88522, -87.63825 41.88449, -87.63845 41.88321, -87.63855 41.88231, -87.63858 41.88104, -87.63855 41.88061, -87.63836 41.87935, -87.63787 41.87794, -87.63778 41.87751, -87.63752 41.87751, -87.63752 41.87731, -87.63775 41.87728, -87.6377 41.87687, -87.63784 41.87684, -87.63778 41.87676, -87.64102 41.87676)))"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

See also https://developer.here.com/blog/how-to-get-the-shape-of-an-area-using-the-here-geocoder-api